# Possible to open photo straight to Adobe Camera Raw?

Tags: raw, file-management, adobe-camera-raw, adobe-bridge

Is there any way to open a photo straight into Adobe Camera Raw without loading Photoshop or anything? I am trying to use my own program to browse my DNG photos and I would like to be able to open them one off into Camera Raw. Is there a way to do this with bridge without having to select the file again? Are there any execution arguments to do this?

Answer (score 1):

ACR is not a stand alone application, but a Photoshop/Bridge plug-in. But if the file extension of your raw files is associated with Photoshop, PS should load and the file should open immediately in ACR when you double click it from explorer.

Functionally, there is no difference then to your requirement.

What your own browsing program does is, of course, determined by this program itself. You could, eg., implement the ability to use PS plugins.